Use Logitech Mx Master 3S mouse's thumb button to activate window switcher using xbindkeys
I use Linux (Ubuntu 24.10) and I used to have a Logitech MX Master 3 mouse. On Linux, the thumb button opened the window switcher (Super+Tab) and I could use the scroll to select one of the windows. Now I have a Logitech MX Master 3S, the newer model, but the thumb button didn't work anymore. That was the context. What I need to do is press the thumb button (recognized as button 10 by xbindkeys) and it executes press Super, press Tab, release Tab, BUT keep pressing Super until I release the thumb button. During the time when the Super key is pressed I want to use the scroll to change the selected window.
What I did, but didn't work is:
...
"xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key Tab'"
b:10

"xte 'keyup Super_L'"
b:10 + Release
...

For some reason, the Super key is still pressed even after I release the button keeping my system very unusable, like, if I would press L, it would understand as Super+L and lock the desktop.
Here are more details about windows switching: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-switching.html.en
